# How can I access the current frame in C++ builder 6 MediaPlayer object when I have paused the video?

Tags: c++, c++builder

How can I access the current frame in C++ builder 6 MediaPlayer object when I have paused the video?

i use a panel or Animate object as its display but I can't find a property or function for neither the MediaPlayer object or its display that lets me access the currently paused frame so that I can be able to copy its pixels information to a bitmap or do some processing on it!

I did this to copy the display image to a bitmap image but it just copies the display(panel or animate) background color:

```
MediaPlayer1->Display->PaintTo(Image1->Canvas, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Wait, C++Buider 6? I haven't seen that name in *years*.

Comment: i know it's old but i have to use it for my project that my stupid teacher has given us because i don't think there is any other way i can do it!

Answer (score 0):

`TMediaPlayer` does not support what you want. You will have to switch to another API, like DirectX or libav, which can give you access to the frame data and expects you to render the frames visually yourself as they are being given to you.